Как правильно сгенерировать сигнатуру?
Есть платёжная система bovapay, и, у меня проблема при работе с api.
https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/11604625/2s9XxvSEda#0807afc7-b7ed-4af5-af78-7fbc97a1e11c
Вот здесь описан способ создания сигнатуры, а я использую следующий код:
    headers = {
  'Signature': sha1("9bb60d153ee990082cbf2164fee2b58add7eb5e9{\"user_uuid\": \"2de9007b-0fb7-4c0f-af2a-d1df5d2e3188\",\
  \"merchant_id\": \"string\",\
  \"amount\": 100,\
  \"callback_url\": \"https://webhook.site/f9d55aae-e554-48c5-b56a-f7cd93fcca7d\",\
  \"redirect_url\": \"https://ya.ru/\",\
  \"email\": \"test@mail.ru\",\
  \"customer_name\": \"Veniamin Epimakhov\",\
  \"currency\": \"rub\",\
  \"payeer_identifier\": \"asdqwe123\",\
  \"lifetime\": 1000,\
  \"payeer_ip\": \"127.0.0.1\",\
  \"payeer_card_number\": \"2200152925135579\"}".encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(),
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

Проблема в том, что я не получаю ответа "print(response.text)", если использую digest, а если использую hexdigest - получаю ответ wrong_signature (менять .encode('utf-8') на b"" пробовал). Ума не приложу, что надо делать, да и делаю впервые...
